# unitpngfix javascript:Void(0) error not allowing to show page with https(securely)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, https

I have a problem with the below one. This Javascript:void(0) is stopping me from showing the page securely with https. What is it actually? I have no idea about javascript. Please help me out!

Thanks alot!

```
var clear="js/clear.gif"; //path to clear.gif

document.write('<script type="text/javascript" id="ct" defer="defer" src="javascript:void(0)"><\/script>')
```

This file has the name js/unitpngfix.js*...i tried to see if it is being used anywhere. Yes, it is being used and all the pages that use this will not be shown as https. In the Master page, it was used like this

Comment: could you add a little more context? some more code would be helpful.  Your code example doesn't show anything to do with https

Comment: Why do you have that `src` in there in the first place?

Comment: This is a very strange piece of code... Explanation would really help.

Comment: I edited with the exra info, i think it might be useful. Please let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Is there a way i can call it securely or change something that solves my problem?

Comment: @Ram, is what you call *extra info* supposed to help? To me it is completely unreadable and looks like garbage. To improve readability of the question either remove this *extra info* or format it properly (indentation, proper variable names, ...).

Comment: @Darin: I apologize! As i told, i have no idea what Javascript is. I did not want to hide any important info. so i had put all that garbage, as you said. I know how much it irritates. I will try to change my view of asking questions. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unitpngfix does not allow you to show pages securely if javascript:void(0) is used. Instead i took off javascript:void(0) off the code.

At least my problem is solved! Thanks for your time guys!